# 17.04 Ubuntu Wireless disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I am running 17.04 64 bit on a Microsoft Surfacebook. Everything seems to work well, except for the WiFi. I will connect to the network, and it will work fine for anywhere from 30 seconds to a few minutes. At that point, the status bar on the top right still indicates that the wireless is on and working, but I will simply get timeouts (and eventually errors indicating a timeout).

Though it seems to turn off randomly, I noticed that if it is still working, downloading just about anything (Google Chrome from the Chrome website, for example) will cause it to stop working seconds after.

Wireless info script output [here](https://pastebin.com/M3m1FRDK)

Any idea on where I could start looking to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here (17.04), on 16.10 I simply issued the following command in a terminal which was essentially disabling the wifi power management...

`sudo iwconfig wlp8s0 power off`

unfortunately it doesn't help anymore
let me know if that worked for you

in your case wlp8s0 would be wlp3s0

//edit 
I used different command 
to get the status (which returned power_save on)
`sudo iw wlp3s0 get power_save`

then disabled it by running:
`sudo iw wlp3s0 set power_save off`

no issues so far :D 
source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145645